# Material Design not compiled when building web components | A thought towards micro front-end

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, web-component, micro-frontend

I have a simple form in Vuejs. I used VueMaterial for same. Now, as a next step I would like to make this form/app/micro-app whatever we can call into a web component/shared components.

My code below

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material';
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css';
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css';
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';

Vue.use(VueMaterial);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
const CustomElm = wrap(Vue, App);

window.customElements.define('custom-elem', CustomElm);
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>


<div id="app">
    <CustomerDetails msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomerDetails from "./components/CustomerDetails.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    CustomerDetails
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**First**, I'm not sure if my approach is correct if my end target is micro front-end.

I mean, (approach #1) Should I use styled components and compile the base/UI/dumb components into  web components. Then use these already compiled web components let's say by Vue.js  for now, in my bigger Vue.js `Form Component` or to go by (approach #2) just doing everything in Vue.js and   in the end compiling the full `Form` component in Vue.js to Web component translates to same?

**Second**, if the two approaches above are same and doesn't make an impact and depends on how big or small I want to make my components. ***Then I'm not able to see VueMaterial in the compiled Web component as per approach #2 above.***

**Third**, if approach #1 makes sense more for doing simpler components first and then using the same in any Framework ( Angular, React, Vuejs) then when I compile the component in Vuejs CLI it removes the `dist` folder and spits out the new one. So, say I want my base/UI/Dumb components as web components from Vuejs + Styled components or Ant Design/material design  to Web components library of these components, how can I manage the compilation part in Vuejs so that I can just do an import

`import {Button, Card, Input} from 'my-web-components';`

Okay, one approach is to manually build each component one by one and copy them inside a folder `my-web-components` and publish the same as `npm package` or keep it as an internal use. So, looking for a better approach here!

Another question that comes to mind is that if I do go by this approach, won't I run into same problem as I ran into now, when I compiled a form component in Vue to Web component and I couldn't get my VueMaterial rendered. My confusion is  I'm not sure if I use styled components for Vuejs, how will my web component compile with exact styling etc.

This is broad but hope I've narrowed all the beginning thoughts to micro front-end approach well here!

Looking forward to your answers.